# Is it rightly used the semicolon at this paragraph

Tags: formality

I appreciate if someone could check whether it is rightly used the semicolon and the word "thereby" at this paragraph, keeping in mind that this is formal english.

If the producer have to assume more production costs, he will transfer them to the final consumer; thereby making this kind of product less affordable.

Comment: The biggest error is "check whether it is rightly used the semicolon".

Answer (score 1):

In this case, what follows the semicolon is neither an independent clause nor a list item as part of a conjunction. So, the semicolon isn't appropriate.

Two minimal ways of fixing it (although there are others) are as follows. (Note that I am also changing *have* to *has*.)

1. Replace the semicolon with a comma:

> If the producer has to assume more production costs, he will transfer them to the final consumer, thereby making this kind of product less affordable.

The comma is appropriate, since what follows it is a dependent clause.

2. Insert wording before *thereby* and slightly modify what comes after it:

> If the producer has to assume more production costs, he will transfer them to the final consumer; this will thereby make this kind of product less affordable.

With the change, what follows the semicolon becomes an independent clause.